# How do I correct use of If Statement using Python

Tags: python

I have some Values like and using python and if statement

```
a = 11
b = 36
c = 70
if (a > 5 and a < 15) and (b > 25 and b < 40) and (c < 100): 
      #do something
```

and while the vales are negative

```
a = -11
b = -36
c = -70
if (a < -5 and a < -15) and (b < -25 and b < -40) and (c > -100): 
      #do something
```

but IF statement is doing anything no error

Comment: Change the second and fourth `<` to `>` in your second example.

Comment: For the second chunk, I think you mean to have `>`s in there. If `a < -15`, `a < -5` will always be true as well.

Comment: The negative version should be `if (a < -5 and a > -15) and (b < -25 and b > -40) and (c > -100)`

Comment: Since 'a' = -11, it is greater than -15, but in your code, the condition was that 'a' is smaller than -15.

Comment: and please let me know the 1st if statements with positive values is correct..?

Comment: Note that the idiomatic way of writing that first conditional in Python is `if 5 < a < 15 and 25 < b < 40 and c < 100:`.

Comment: thank you for the help i have resolve. it's fine now and please answer the question I will mark is close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your if statement is not doing anything is because it evaluates down to being false. This is because your comparison operators (the < and >) are looking for a to be less than -5 (True when a = - 11) and -15 (False when a = -11), and for b to be less than -25 (True when b = -36) and -40 (False when b = -36).

If I evaluate your code it looks like this:

```
a = -11
b = -36
c = -70

if (a < -5 and a < -15) and (b < -25 and b < -40) and (c > -100): 
# The first comparison paranthesis: (a < -5 and a < -15) evaluates to (True and False)
# The second comparison paranthesis: (b < -25 and b < -40) evaluates to (True and False)
# The last comparison paranthesis: (c > -100) evaluates to (True)
# if (True and False) and (True and False) and (True)
# if False and False and True
# if False
      #do something
```